# Find if combination of column elements exists on another row

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to extract rows where the combination of elements in geneA and geneB are present in two or more rows. My infile data.xlsx looks like:

```
chrA_x          ens_geneA       geneA   chrB            ens_geneB       geneB
chr1:92092600   ENSG00000189195 BTBD8   chr2:164084669  ENSG00000237844 AC016766.1
chr1:121498879  ENSG00000233432 AL592   chr9:2781522    ENSG00000080608 PUM3
chr1:200152569  ENSG00000116833 NR5A2   chr7:112680583  ENSG00000223646 AC002463.1
chr1:205618297  ENSG00000158711 ELK4    chr7:32968816   ENSG00000122642 FKBP9
chr1:92092600   ENSG00000189195 BTBD8   chr2:164084669  ENSG00000237844 AC016766.1
chr1:92092600   ENSG00000189195 BTBD8   chr9:2781522    ENSG00000080608 PUM3
```

Expected output:

```
chrA_x          ens_geneA       geneA   chrB            ens_geneB       geneB
chr1:92092600   ENSG00000189195 BTBD8   chr2:164084669  ENSG00000237844 AC016766.1
```

My code so far only gives rows where the elements in geneA and geneB are duplicated, not that the combination is duplicated :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

pd.options.display.max_colwidth = 100
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
df =  pd.read_excel("data.xlsx")
dups = np.logical_and((df[df.duplicated(['geneA'])]), (df[df.duplicated(['geneB'])]))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first combine the columns and test whether that combination is duplicated. Assuming that no comma (`,`) can exist in the fields, you could use:

```
df.loc[(df.geneA + ',' + df.geneB).duplicated()]
```